# GUI for minimalistic XML database

Tags: python, xml, database

I would like to create a very simple database describing the projects that I have worked on in the past, with a small number of text and numerical fields (volume, name of client, date, etc...).
The solution that comes to mind for this would be an XML format (with individual files for each project, or a single file containing everything).
I could of course program this with Python (I know that there are simple commands for this) but this application seems to obvious that there must already be simple GUIs doing exactly this.

So my question is: are there simple GUI programs (running in Linux) that enable the creation and management of such extremely simple XML databases ?

Thank you !

Comment: Any particular reason that XML comes to mind? It's useful as a self-describing data transport format, but as a database? umm...

Comment: I would cite my ignorance as the main reason :)
(plus the fact that it's more or less human-readable)

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data in a MySQL database, then [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) can [export that data](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/export) to many formats, including XML.

Comment: Are there any simple GUIs for this purpose ?

Comment: phpmyadmin is a web-based GUI interface. It can also export to [JSON](http://www.json.org/), which is more readable than XML.